# Drupal: how do I retrieve the select type values from a module Config form?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm new to Drupal and am trying to build a module. Part of what this module does is allow you to add preset classes from a drop down field.

For the most part I've got this working but for one thing: I seem to only be able to retrieve the select options name, not it's value.

The code I have is below.

In the config form creation function I have:

```
$styles = array(
  'None' => '',
  'Blue Buttons' => 'btn blue-btn',
  'Red Buttons' => 'btn red-btn',
);

$mymodule_form['style'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#title' => t('Style'),
  '#description' => t('Style for buttons'),
  '#default_value' => $form_values['style'],
  '#empty_option' => t('- Select -'),
  '#options' => drupal_map_assoc(array_keys($styles)),
);
```

But, when I run `dpm($this->options['style']);` later on in my code when I want to use those styles, I get the key names return (eg `Button Red`)

Would anyone know how I can retrieve the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using `drupal_map_assoc` when I didn't need to.

```
'#options' => $styles,
```

is fine.

(Also, I had my key names and values around the wrong way).